# Installing Ubuntu on a Mac with USB stick made on Windows/Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, macbook

I've been searching all over the internet with absolutely no luck, just how to triple boot, which doesn't help me at all.

I have a MacBook Pro (2007) and I attempted to upgrade the OS. It fails every time so I'm stuck in a loop, and cannot do anything about it.

My only other computers are my Windows box, and an Ubuntu box. Is there any way I can make a bootable USB stick of Ubuntu 14.04 to install Ubuntu onto this MacBook Pro? Or do I NEED to use a Mac to make the image?

Answer (score 0):

You make the image with any OS.

**Create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu**

To create a USB stick from which you can install Ubuntu, you must first download Ubuntu. Then, follow these instructions:

1.
Insert a USB stick with at least 2GB of free space.

2.
Open the dash and search for Startup Disk Creator.

3.
Select the Startup Disk Creator to launch the app.

4
Click 'Other' to choose the downloaded ISO file.
5
Select the file and click 'Open'.

6
Select the USB stick in the bottom box and click 'Make Startup Disk'.

7
That’s it! When the process completes, you’ll be ready to restart your computer and begin installing Ubuntu.

**Create a bootable USB stick on OS X**

1.[Download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) Ubuntu Desktop.

2
Open the Terminal (in /Applications/Utilities/ or query Terminal in Spotlight).

3
Convert the .iso file to .img using the convert option of hdiutil e.g.,

`hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/ubuntu.iso`

Note: OS X tends to put the .dmg ending on the output file automatically.

4
Run `diskutil list` to get the current list of devices.

5
Insert your flash media.

6
Run `diskutil list` again and determine the device node assigned to your flash media (e.g. /dev/disk2).

7
Run `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN`

(replace N with the disk number from the last command; in the previous example, N would be 2).

8
Execute

`sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m`

(replace /path/to/downloaded.img with the path where the image file is located; for example, ./ubuntu.img or ./ubuntu.dmg).

- Using /dev/rdisk instead of /dev/disk may be faster
- If you see the error dd: Invalid number '1m', you are using GNU dd. Use the same command but replace bs=1m with bs=1M
- If you see the error dd: /dev/diskN: Resource busy, make sure the disk is not in use. Start the 'Disk Utility.app' and unmount (don't eject) the drive

9
Run

`diskutil eject /dev/diskN`
and remove your flash media when the command completes.

10
Restart your Mac and press alt/option key while the Mac is restarting to choose the USB stick.

---

If Ubuntu is not available in grub, run `sudo update-grub`